# Is use of negative sign in faraday's law a convention because of using right hand thumb rule?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

We use right hand thumb rule to relate $dS$ and $dl$ like if $dS$ points in the direction of thumb then direction of $dl$ is taken in the direction of fingers but if we use left hand thumb rule to relate $dS$ and $dl$ then there is no need of negative sign in the equation?
$$\oint\vec{E'}\cdot\vec{dl'}=-\frac{d\phi_B}{dt} $$

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/639794/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic OP seems to really want an answer...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the minus sign in Maxwell's third equation imply?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/647146/what-does-the-minus-sign-in-maxwells-third-equation-imply)

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't directly due to the right-hand rule as far as I know.

It is because of [Lenz's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law). Lenz's law states that a change in electric field will *oppose* whatever is driving the change.

For example, if a magnetic flux is changing in one way, Lenz's law asserts that the electric field created by this changing flux will be in such a direction to induce another magnetic field which will try to *cancel* the change in initial field.

Fundamentally, this is derived from the conservation of energy - the alternative is an exponentially growing magnetic field which keeps increasing its own magnitude, thus creating energy from nothing!

Going back to your equation, the minus sign is simply the statement of this opposition of changing magnetic field and induced electric field.

Comment: How do you know that negative sign signifies that opposition

Comment: I am saying mathematically what negative sign signifies is a coincidence because of using right hand thumb rule.

Comment: Like if I tell you, you said that it hand nothing to do with right hand thumb rule then that means we can also use left hand thumb rule , integral E•dl is always true and it always gives correct value of emf with correct sign

Comment: I understand what you're saying. My intuition is that there should also be a minus sign even if you use the left-hand coordinate system, but I can't quite think exactly why. Let me chew it over and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I am pretty much not able to understand what it actually means everyone has a different answer regarding that.

Comment: But I believe that it's just a part of mathematics and it's not physics and we alter the things so that they are more sensible to us and more intuitive but that doesn't actually means that they are correct

Comment: Yes intuitively we tend to say that if there is something opposing then relate negative sign with that and that's not wrong because it satisfies our intuition but we also have to change things mathematically so that both , our intuition and mathematics are satisfied

Comment: Consider the classic example of Faraday's law - a wire moving in a uniform B field. In a left-hand coordinate system, you would find the EMF induced in the opposite direction to a right-hand one. However, this would then produce a force on the wire in the same direction in both coordinate systems since you again use the RH/LH rule to work out in which direction the force due to the current from the EMF (i.e. $\vec{F} = \vec{B}\times\vec{l} I$) pushes the wire, I think.

Comment: I am not saying that to say about a fact we can change conventions

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite know what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124833/discussion-between-jumbot-and-manik-singh).

Comment: You can't use left hand thumb rule for finding direction of magnetic field due current carring wire because it's direction is a fact

Answer (score 0):

Whatever rule we use to relate the sense of the flux *produced by* a current circulating in the loop in a given sense, we must use the same rule when relating the emf (which has a circulation sense) to the flux change that produces it. Then to comply with Lenz's law we need the minus sign!

This works with either a left hand rule or a right hand rule.

Comment: I understand that what you are trying to say is the rule which we use in finding the direction of magnetic field produced in a current carring wire that rule we have to use in relating dS and dl? Is that correct

Comment: If What I am saying is actually what you are trying to explain then why we have to do that

Comment: But why, to define a fact we use a particular rule which agrees with the actual fact, but relation between direction of dS and dl is our creation it's not natural fact then why we can't relate it by our willing so that mathematics is satisfied and facts are also satisfied

Comment: Your first comment... No; for one thing, my answer involved induced emf. Yours doesn't seem to. Your last comment... I find it hard to follow, but my basic point is that whatever rule we use to associate a circulation direction *around* a loop with direction of flux *through* it, we must apply it consistently.

Comment: I am not associating direction of dl with direction of flux but I am associating direction of dl with direction of dS and dS is not fixed

Comment: And what do you mean by "circulation direction"?

Comment: Clockwise or anticlockwise (when viewing loop from an agree viewpoint).

Comment: Please explain by using notations instead of terms

Comment: You are saying to use LHR or RHR but to determine the direction of flux produced by current circulating in a particular direction in rotational sense we have to use RHR because for particular direction of circulation of current there is fixed direction of flux produced so it's fact it's not choice("Whatever rule we use to relate the sense of the flux produced by a current circulating in the loop in a given sense").

Answer (score 0):

In principle we could use opposite orientations for the line and surface integral and the negative sign would vanish but (by convention) we use the direction as given by the right hand rule.

Suppose you know the electric field at all points in space. In absence of a convention there would always be a sign ambiguity and you wouldn't know whether Faraday's law says the flux is increasing or decreasing as the surface integral could be calculated using either of the two orientations.

Comment: Are you talking about direction of dS to be with magnetic field and opposite to magnetic field and in that case there are two signs possible for d∅?

Comment: Effectively yes.

Comment: Why do I have to know that with sign of rate of change of flux  that flux is increasing or decreasing?

Comment: If we use left hand rule by convention then -ve sign is not needed then then what will +ve sign signify?

Comment: Well if we didn't know whether the flux will increase or decrease then Faraday's law would be incomplete.

Comment: Even if you use left hand rule for the orientation of the curve and the corresponding surface you'll still get that minus sign

Comment: That has nothing to do with right hand rule

Comment: Rate of change of flux is determined by fixing dS vector only nothing more so no right hand rule used

Comment: For equation to be consistent (mentioned in the question) if we use left hand rule then -ve sign from equation should be changed to positive

Comment: Read this article https://drive.google.com/file/d/14A2wThHeOxJihUxveNO9-fJOxxqL9Z6b/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

The right hand rule is related to the convention that the positive sense of rotation is the anti-clockwise from the point of view of who is looking to the plane.

Maybe it is related to the convention that the North is "up", and if we imagine looking at the earth from "above", it is rotating anti-clockwise. Old arabic maps depicted the Europe below Africa, so it is just a convention.

But anyway, once a convention is agreed, it must be followed. In the case of Maxwell equations, if we get rid of the minus sign in the Faraday Law by changing convention, it is moved to the Ampere's Law.

Comment: What is short answer yes or no to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using right hand thumb rule is the reason why there is negative sign in equation of faraday's law. If we use left hand rule then instead of using negative sign we have to replace it by positive for consistency of equation. So, that means conventions are changing sign and so particularly there is no physical significance of negative sign in equation of faraday's law. People usually relate negative sign with some opposition intuitively which in this case is induced emf opposing change in magnetic flux. So, to satisfy their intuition they somehow find negative sign to be the contributor for the reason of opposition. In that case if we use left hand rule then we can also say that positive sign is contributor for opposition of change in flux because equation is still following Lenz law if we have to find out what thing in the equation is doing that opposition thing. I feel many things in the equation are more or less responsible for that opposition behaviour.